# Breaking a Data modeling

Tags: database, ms-access, data-modeling, ms-access-2016

I am new to data modelling and I am doing a course to improve on it. I have been asked to prepare a date model based on a brief I have been given.[image: Brief]

I was told my solution I had prepared was flawed and to break it by entering in lots of data. I have done this and I can't see any problem with it. Maybe I am just approaching it wrong and don't realise I am entering in the information wrong. Maybe I should have an invoice to bookings as a 1:1 relationship but I don't know how I would do this. Any help what so ever would mean the world to me as I have spent a couple of hours in trying to break and mess around with my model. [image: Data Model]

Comment: You need to give us a higher resolution picture that is not blurry. I can barely decipher anything.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your data model as described.  I would personally make a few changes but nothing that is broken.

Comment: @ChrisTravers sorry only seen there what problems would you make to the erd. I have found that i need to have the invoice number created first before filling in the information which i know is not right but i have been unable to fix this after many attempts

Comment: If it were me, I would break off pre-rental and post-rental checks into a different table so you could do better auditing and tracking, but that's not "broken." And "lots of data" isn't going to break it.

Comment: So are you saying i should have a table for intial bookings and then another one when the booking is complete ??